# google gantt chart - subtasks?

Tags: charts, gantt-chart

Is there any way to create subtasks in [google gantt Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart)?
I see there is a way to group tasks by color, but since my gantt schedule contains many tasks (approx 100 tasks), I need a way to get a overview of the schedule. Is there any way to create subtasks and collapse them if the user just need a overview of the schedule?

Comment: no _subtasks with collapse_ but you could use more than one chart -- summary and detail...

Comment: More than one chart Will not be optimal for the users.. Im thinking more a way to add some Buttons to choose if the user wants to display the subtasks or not. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do this so far is by grouping. For example, list your Primary task in cell A1 and your subtasks in cells A2-A6. Highlight rows 2-6 on the sheet, then right click the highlighted cells to bring up the submenu. Choose "View more row actions," then "Group rows 2-6." You should now have a plus sign next to your Primary task that, when clicked on, will collapse or uncollapse the tasks under your Primary task.

[Sample Image of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASX9m.png)